# Dynamically import components in Gatsby

Tags: webpack, gatsby

I'm running a number of Gatsby sites from a monorepo and use gatsby-plugin-loadable-components-ssr to display different widgets (components) on different sites. When looking at the production bundle though, there's a reference to each available widgets' file path even if they are not being used at the current page.

As I'm thinking of expanding my widget configuration setup into a basic page builder I'm going to be looking at adding a large number of new widgets and would therefore very much prefer if the bundle wasn't bloated with references to unused components.

Has anyone successfully achieved something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to try out the WIP work done here: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/24903
(Issue: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/18689). This will be the way forward to programmatically import components / have the desired code-splitting.